# Python psycopg2 dynamic where clause with optional AND based on conditional

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

This probably isn't a new question but I have not been able to find a decent solution after googling and digging through SO for a while.  I want to have a conditional AND added to my WHERE clause based on if a variable is set or not.

I could put in a ternary into the string format but that does not seem like a good solution.

```
def run_query(start_date, end_date, value):
    query = """
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = %(value)s {date_clause}""".format(date_clause = "AND start_date >= %(start_date)s AND end_date <= %(end_date)s" if start_date is not None and end_date is not Null else "")

cursor.execute(query, {"start_date": None, "end_date": None, "value": value})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Postgres function [`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

```
query = """
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE column = %(value)s 
AND otherColumn = COALESCE(%(otherValue)s, '')

"""
```

When `otherValue` is None then will be converted to Postgres `NULL` and `COALESCE()` return an empty string.

Comment: thanks forgot about COALESCE I don't think that would work if my conditional check is dates though, not sure if an empty string would work.  Edited my post to show what I ended up doing.  I am looking into pyscopg2 sql.SQL composition as well http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql

Comment: Be aware that this can be extremely slow when you have more data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426436/postgresql-coalesce-performance-problem